# Chrome is not getting launched when running selenium script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

Earlier it was working but now when trying to run the script, it launches the chrome but after that no response.

*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[contains(text(),'LOGIN')]}

Below is my error details:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),'LOGIN')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15.04 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-6P0RF6P', ip: '192.168.1.32', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab), userDataDir=C:\Users\Himanshu\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=67.0.3396.99, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: ffba310f04b236c97837d64c36192716
```

Comment: What is version of your Selenium JAR or dependency?

Comment: I am using 3.13,0

Comment: Now I am trying with Firefox but still not working.
I have installed latest firefox with Gecko driver.. i am unable to use.. How to set gecko driver as i am using maven project

Comment: What error you are getting when use FF and gecko?

Comment: Paste your code. also go through the link on how to ask a question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask